# search in a local database (sql) with AS3

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, actionscript-3, air

I've got an AS3 code that I want to link with a php. That php search in a database (sql) and send results to my AS3 code.

So I've got 3 files : my project (FLA file), my php file, and my sql file.

I would like to do this operation offline (local).

How can I do ?

In my AS3 code I've got :

```
var urlreq = new URLRequest("myPHP.php");
    urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var urlVars = new URLVariables();

    urlVars.theport = "New-York";
    urlreq.data = urlVars;  

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlreq);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.load(urlreq);
```

In my php :

```
$theport = $_POST['theport'];
...
```

linked to a conn.php file :

```
$cfg_hote = 'mys****.perso';        
$cfg_base = '******';           
$cfg_user = '*****';            
$cfg_password = '****rhx';
```

And I've got an sql file uploaded at phpmyadmin.ovh.net

So now, how can I do this operation offline (local) ?

---

EDIT

So, I've created a db file with SQLite Browser. Now, how can I link my AS3 code (AIR apps) to my php to my database ?

1. My php got the code to search into the database.
2. My database is created and is in the same folder as the project.

Comment: In order to use php locally you need to setup sql server locally. If you want to use AIR SDLLite feature you need to have that DB file, but you need to be sure that DB is compatible with SQLite, you can use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to check that

Comment: [SQLError #3125](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/578840) and here: [Working with local SQL databases in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html) - you do not need php, but you have to sync databases somehow (if you want online and offline mode)

Comment: you can check if there a database file (before sqlconnection)- if no database file you have to create new one - Best Regards !

Comment: Ok, I've created a db file (I've edited my post). What should I do now ?

Comment: Use sql to sync the two I guess. Read everything from the sql file and create a php file that can update or modify your tables however. Then send it over using vars like you're already doing.