# search and replace multiple words in AS3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, text, replace

I've got this code in my AS3 :

```
var str:String = mySharedObject.data.theDate;
var search:String = "monday";
var replace:String = "";

function strReplace(str:String, search:String, replace:String):String {
 return str.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

Is it possible to tell the code to search for "monday or tuesday or wednsday, or thursday, or friday" and replace them with "_" ?

And, secondly, is it possible to tell the code to search for "January" and replaced it by "01", "February" by "02"...etc ? (in one line if it's possible) ?

Thx

---

**EDIT**

I'd like to do something as simple as that :

```
str.replace( "monday"||"tuesday"||"wednsday" , "" );
```

Or

```
var search:String ="tuesday","wednsday","thursday";
```

But it's not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a regular expression which is implemented in the [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) class in AS3. The pattern passed into [`String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) can be a `RegExp` which can be used to do type of matching you want.

A simple regular expression to match English language work days could look like this:

```
(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)
```

which is Regular Expression for "match Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday or Thursday or Friday". Note that this almost certainly isn't the best regex for this but it's simple and it works. There's a link where you can learn more about regexes at the bottom of this answer.

This regex can be put into a function that takes the string to search, the string to replace matches with and a string called `flag`. `flag` is a list of options that modify how the regex works. The [docs for the `RegExp` construction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html#RegExp%28%29) provide complete details. This function might look like:

```
private function replaceDay(str:String, replace:String, flag:String = ''):String
{
    var search:RegExp = new RegExp("(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)", flag);         
    return str.replace(search, replace);
}
```

You can then test it out (I've run it all in Flash Builder successfully):

```
// Replace a single, normally capitalized day name
var monday:String = "Monday the 1st";
trace(replaceDay(monday, "REDACTED"));  // REDACTED the 1st

// Replace multiple normally capitalized day names
var mondayAndTuesday:String = "Either Monday or Tuesday works for me";
trace(replaceDay(mondayAndTuesday, "", "g"));  // Either  or  works for me

// Replace a single day name regardless of capitalization
var lowerCaseWednesday:String = "wednesday";
trace(replaceDay(lowerCaseWednesday, "yadsendew", "i"));  // yadsendew

var weirdCaseThursday:String = "tHurSdaY";
trace(replaceDay(weirdCaseThursday, "It's actually 'Thursday'.", "i"));  // It's actually 'Thursday'.

// Replace multiple day names regardless of capitalization
var friday:String = "FriDAY FRIDAY friday";
trace(replaceDay(friday, "Something", "ig")); // Something Something Something
```

---

As for your question about replacing month names with numbers that is possible as well. The last example in the [docs for `String.replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) shows how to use a function as the `replace` value. Since StackOverflow prefers [one post, one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) you should remove it from this post and post another question.

---

For more info on regular expressions check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Super Thx for the very complete answer !

Comment: If you have an answer as good as this one for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078950/search-in-a-local-database-sql-with-as3  it will be perfect ! ;-)

Comment: Read the docs for String.replace for replacing month names with numbers.. Didn't understand very well...

Comment: You need to ask another question for the months part.